# Should we have a sandbox?

Tags: discussion

(See [Worldbuilding's sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for an example of how this might look.)

Essentially, a question sandbox is a large, community-edited meta question that will allow users to post prospective questions they have in mind (to ask on the main site) as answers to the meta question. Other users can then give them feedback in the comments on how to improve the quality of their question, as well as advise them in terms of whether their potential question is on-topic for the site. Once sufficient feedback has been given, that meta answer will then be deleted to clear up some space for other new, potential questions.

Such a sandbox may help decrease the flow of off-topic, low-quality questions asked on the main site. What are your thoughts on the idea?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure a sandbox would be a great idea... right now. At least, I don't think we've demonstrated a great need for one. Sandboxes are great in principle, but in practice, they're a lot harder to manage, and have less of an impact on quality than you'd think.

**Typically, the only people who are going to take the time to sandbox a question are those people who are already putting in the requisite effort to ask good questions.** So if our goal is to raise the quality of the site, this probably won't do it, and we'd be better using the regular process of closing and leaving comments asking for specific improvements.

That being said, there's some value in a place for people who want to improve their questions to workshop them before posting - and for now, I'd say that's a good place for chat to be. Often, especially on Literature, this sort of workshopping requires some interactivity and back-and-forth, for which a sandbox might not be as good as chat - at least for now.

If, at a later point, there's a good reason and good need for making a sandbox, though, I'd still personally be open to the idea.

Comment: I put in time to writing good questions, but I think I for one could do so more effectively with a sandbox. Especially in beta, when we are still figuring things out.

Comment: I can point to experiences with Worldbuilding's sandbox that confirm this. It does help new users, but it also strongly attracts those who are already asking excellent question.

Comment: @Benjamin if the target audience isn't new users, then perhaps creating a new chat room would be a good idea?

Comment: @Hamlet I am not sure if that really solves the problem I raised in response to Rand's answer, but we could give it a shot.

Comment: @Benjamin, if the problem is that the feedback you're getting in chat doesn't conform to the reaction you get on the site, then I'm not sure how a meta sandbox would be any different.

Comment: @Hamlet It wouldn't just be who is in chat then, but also people over a period of time.

Answer (score 8):

> Such a sandbox may help decrease the flow of off-topic, low-quality questions asked on the main site.

Is there a problem with excessive off-topic, low-quality questions asked on the main site? Or to put it another way, **what problem are you trying to solve here?**

If we start to get overrun with badly written questions which could easily have been made better with the help of some feedback on meta, then we can consider implementing this idea. For now, I don't see any point in it. Our few downvoted/closed questions tend to be poorly received because of the essential nature of the question, and there aren't many of them anyway.

Comment: I agree with your premise, but not with your conclusion.

Comment: If I could, I would upvote and downvote, but since I can't, I shan't vote.

Comment: @Benjamin What does that mean? You agree that we don't have excessive off-topic, low-quality questions, but still think we should have a sandbox?

Comment: Yes, because I know it would help me and I assume it would help others like me. I often see people pop into chat to ask about something, which those there approve of, but then gets a bad response on site.

Comment: @Benjamin What makes you think a sandbox will produce different results? For the record, I've seen plenty of cases where chat was just as productive as a sandbox, if not more.

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't know, but chat hasn't worked great for me, so I see no harm in trying a sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

There are several reasons I can think of for why not to have a sandbox:

1.) **If you are going to post in the sandbox, you can probably post a good question anyway.**

If you're going to post a question to the sandbox at this stage in the site, you are probably concerned enough about quality to post a quality question *without the sandbox*.

2.) **There aren't a lot of bad questions now.**

We don't have a lot of bad or off-topic questions right now - at least, none that our downvotes/close votes can't take care of. If it ever becomes a problem, then we might start considering the idea again, but...

3.) **New users won't know about it/care.**

The majority of the users who would post bad questions/off topic questions are new users, who are the ones that would need the sandbox - but how would they know about it? We could point them to it in the comments, but why should they care? They'll just ignore it most of the time. And if they don't ignore it, that leads back to the first point.

4.) **We *can* use chat for this.**

Most users won't care if you drop in in the middle of a chat conversation to ask for help writing a question. The lone exception would be if we're having a serious policy discussion, which should probably be on Meta anyway. I'll try to help if you drop in!

Comment: Re (4): Of course, legitimate queries about the site's subject always take priority over whatever random chatter is going on

Answer (score -6):

**Yes**, we should have a sandbox, because I know that it would help me and it would probably help many others as well. For my case, I know that I often want to ask in chat before posting a question, but people in chat are often talking about a different topic, but this would allow me to run it by others before asking my question.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with thirdspace that should be fixed, rather than run around the long way by creating a fourthspace.